# Angular 2 page transition while leaving page

Tags: angular, angular2-animation

I am trying to do page transition animation using Angular 2. The basic requirement is that the page should there should be animation while entering and leaving the page.The animation works fine while entering the page but while leaving the page to another page,it directly jumps to the new page without executing the leaving animation.

```
Transition.ts

import {trigger, state, animate, style, transition} from '@angular/core';

export function optionsTransition() {

    return trigger('optionsTransition', [
        state('void', style({transform: 'translateZ(-500px)'}) ),
       state('*', style({transform: 'translateZ(0)'}) ),
        transition(':enter', [
            // style({transform: 'translateZ(-500px)',opacity:0}),
            animate('0.5s ease-in-out', style({transform: 'translateZ(0px)'}))
        ]),
        transition(':leave', [
          // style({transform: 'translateZ(0px)',opacity:1}),
          animate('0.5s ease-in-out', style({transform: 'translateZ(0px)'}))
        ])
    ]);
}


component.html


<div  style="-webkit-perspective: 1000;">

  <div class="content-container" [@optionsTransition]="customAnimation.state">

    <swiper  overlay-controls [config]="swipperConfig">
      <div *ngFor="let option of Options" class="swiper-slide tile"  fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="center center"
           [routerLink]="[option.nextstate]" routerLinkActive="active" (click)="clickOnOption()">

         <img [src]="option.icon" alt="" style="width:100%; height:100%"/>
        <div class="imageContent"  [ngStyle]="{'background-image': 'url(' +option.icon + ')'}">

        </div>

        <span class="label">{{option.title}}</span>
          <span class="label label1">{{option.info}}</span>

      </div>
    </swiper>

</div>




Component.ts


import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { optionsTransition } from './options-transition.animation';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-options',
    animations: [optionsTransition()],
   // host: {'[@optionsTransition]': ''},
  templateUrl: './options.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./options.component.css']
})
export class OptionsComponent implements OnInit {
    customAnimation:any = {custom:true, state:""};

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {


  }

    swipperConfig:any = {
        direction:'horizontal',
        scrollbar: '',
        scrollbarHide: false,
        slidesPerView: 'auto',
        centeredSlides: false,
        spaceBetween: 3,
        grabCursor: false
    }

   Options : any[] = []

}
```

the targeted animation is coming of the page from behind(along z-axis)and displaying it to forefront
Am I missing something in the code especially in  transition.ts?I am using Angular 2.3.1

Answer (score 0):

I revised at transition.ts

```
Transition.ts

import {trigger, state, animate, style, transition} from '@angular/core';

export function optionsTransition() {

return trigger('optionsTransition', [
    state('enter', style({transform: 'translateZ(-500px)'}) ),
    state('leave', style({transform: 'translateZ(0)'}) ),
    transition(':enter', [
        // style({transform: 'translateZ(-500px)',opacity:0}),
        animate('0.5s ease-in-out', style({transform: 'translateZ(0px)', opacity: 1}))
    ]),
    transition(':leave', [
      // style({transform: 'translateZ(0px)',opacity:1}),
      animate('0.5s ease-in-out', style({transform: 'translateZ(-500px)', opacity: 0}))
    ])
]);
```

}

Comment: should we mention customAnimation.state="leave" before leaving the page,so that leave animation is carried out?if so how?or will it be considered automatically while routing?

Comment: i think it will be considered automatically while routing before leaving the page. so have you done as i mentioned?

Comment: yes,but not succeeded yet in it .The leave animation is still not working,whereas enter animation is working fine

Comment: ok, let me try again. did you revised translatez(-500px) at second transition(':leave')?

Comment: does it work well? so how did you do? what was wrong?

Comment: `export function optionsTransition() {

    return trigger('optionsTransition', [
        state('enter', style({transform: 'translateZ(0px)'}) ),
       state('leave', style({transform: 'translateZ(0px)'}) ),
        transition(':enter', [
       style({transform: 'translateZ(-500px)'}),
            animate('0.5s ease-in-out', style({transform: 'translateZ(-500px)'}))
        ]),
        transition(':leave', [
          style({transform: 'translateZ(-500px)'}),
          animate('0.5s ease-in-out', style({transform: 'translateZ(-500px)'}))
        ])
    ]);
}`

Comment: I changed the code to this but there was no effect on leave animation